# (Java) Substrings & Reading data from two files using hashmap

Tags: java, hashmap, substring

If I had a `.txt` file called `animals` that had `fishfroggoat` etc. in it, and another file called `owners` that had something like:

```
fish:jane
frog:mark
goat:joe
```

how could I go about pairing the pets to their owners? I'm fairly sure a HashMap would be good here, but I'm stuck. I put the animal text into a string, but I don't know how to break it up into 4 characters properly.

Any help would be great.

Sorry I didn't add any code, but thanks to you guys' help (especially Ted Hopps) I worked it out and, more importantly, understood it. :-)

Comment: post your both sample input text files here

Answer (score 1):

There are various approaches. The most direct is to split it using the [`substring`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring%28int,%20int%29) method:

```
String animals = "fishfroggoat";
String fish = animals.substring(0, 4);
String frog = animals.substring(4, 8);
String goat = animals.substring(8); // or (8, 12)
```

If you have an arbitrarily long list of 4-character animals, you can do this:

```
String animals = "fishfroggoatbear";
int n = animals.length() / 4;
String[] animalArray = new String[n];
for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
    animalArray[i] = animals.substring(4*i, 4*i + 4);
}
```

You can split the pet/owner strings using [`split`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29):

```
String rawData = "fish:jane";
String[] data = rawData.split(":");
String pet = data[0];
String owner = data[1];
```

Comment: Thanks for this, it became a lot clearer with your explanation. Much appreciated. (Sorry I can't upvote or anything - no reputation :( ).

Answer (score 0):

Use String split as given below.

String msg=fish:jane;
msg.split(":")

Then it will make array separate by ":".

Answer (score 0):

This is how you split a string into 4-character chunks in just one line:

```
String[] animals = input.split("(?<=\\G....)");
```

This may seem like black magic, so I'll try to demystify it. Welcome to the dark art of regular expressions...

The `String.split()` method splits the string on every match to the specified regex. So let's look at the regex:

```
(?<=\\G....)
```

- The construct `(?<=regex)` is a "positive look behind" for the regex, meaning that the characters preceding the point in the input *between* characters (because a look behind is zero-width) must natch the regex.
- The regex `\G` (coded as `\\G` as a java String constant) means "start of previous match" but also initially matches start of input.
- The regex `....` matches any 4 characters.

Thus, when expressed in English, the regex `(?<=\\G....)` means "after every characters".

IF anyone is interested, removing `\G` and splitting on `(?<=\....)` causes it to split on *every* character after the 4th = it just means "preceded by 4 characters" - you need the `\G` to find 4 *new* characters.

---

Here's some test code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    String input = "fishfroggoatbear";
    String[] animals = input.split("(?<=\\G....)");
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(animals));
}
```

Output:

```
[fish, frog, goat, bear]
```